# How to fix AppArmor `could not open` error when installing php+mysql?

Tags: mysql, apparmor

I want to install `php5-imap php5-ldap php5-curl`

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imap php5-ldap php5-curl
```

I get this error:

```
AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld at line 9: Could not open 'abstractions/mysql'
```

How can this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the file abstractions/mysql. This happened to me when I tried to completely remove MySQL before reinstalling it. I fixed this issue by replacing the file with a copy from another server. The contents of my file looks something like this:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#    Copyright (C) 2002-2006 Novell/SUSE
#    Copyright (C) 2013 Christian Boltz
#
#    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#    modify it under the terms of version 2 of the GNU General Public
#    License published by the Free Software Foundation.
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------

   /var/lib/mysql{,d}/mysql{,d}.sock rw,
   /{var/,}run/mysql{,d}/mysql{,d}.sock rw,
   /usr/share/{mysql,mysql-community-server,mariadb}/charsets/ r,
   /usr/share/{mysql,mysql-community-server,mariadb}/charsets/*.xml r,
```

Try creating the file and adding the above contents with:

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/mysql
```

Comment: I don't know where else I would have found this file!

Comment: This answer helps me. Where a hell can someone find this file's content? Maybe additional comment - files in /etc/apparmor.d/abstractions have 644 permissions.

Answer (score 1):

See if the Ubuntu wiki helps : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor

Specifically,

> When debugging, it may also be useful
>   to put apparmor into 'complain' mode.
>   This will allow your application to
>   function normally while apparmor
>   reports accesses that are not in the
>   profile. To enable 'complain' mode,
>   use:
>
> ```
> sudo aa-complain /path/to/bin
> ```
>
> where '/path/to/bin' is the absolute
>   path to the binary, as reported in the
>   'profile=...' portion of the 'audit'
>   entry. Eg:
>
> ```
> sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/slapd
> ```
>
> To re-enable enforcing mode, use
>   'aa-enforce' instead:
>
> ```
> sudo aa-enforce /path/to/bin
> ```
>
> To disable a profile:
>
> ```
> sudo touch /etc/apparmor.d/disable/path.to.bin
> sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/path.to.bin
> ```
>
> To disable a profile in Ubuntu 10.10 and earlier:
>
> `sudo touch /etc/apparmor.d/disable/path.to.bin sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/path.to.bin`
>
> in 11.04 and later:
>
> `sudo aa-disable /etc/apparmor.d/path.to.bin`
>
> To disable all of AppArmor
>   for testing purposes, boot with `apparmor=0` on the kernel command
>   line.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:
(source: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/unable-to-install-snap-from-store-or-locally/4629/15)

First remove apparmor and snapd (in my case the error was related to snapd, I don't think you have to remove it in your case)

```
sudo apt-get purge apparmor
sudo apt-get purge apparmor-profiles
sudo apt-get purge apparmor-utils
sudo apt-get remove snapd snapd-confine
```

Now Install back them all (again, you may not need to install snapd):

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
sudo apt install apparmor-profiles apparmor-profiles-extra vim-addon-manager
sudo apt install snapd snapd-login-service snap-confine
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but maybe someone will find it useful.

Sometimes pieces of application are split in separate packages. Same goes for apparmor profiles. They are split in packages `apparmor-profiles` and `apparmor-profiles-extra`. So, if you have some profiles missing, install `apparmor-profiles-extra`.